# How to render child function component when data is change?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I import a function component B, `onChange` or `onComplete` can re-render B when data only change in B.

B:

```
const B = (props) => {
  const { lightValue } = props;
  console.log('lightValue is', lightValue);
  const [brightness, setBrightness] = useState(lightValue);

  const returnLightValue = (value) => {
    props.callBack(value);
  };

  return (
    <VerticalSlider
      value={brightness}
      onChange={(value) => returnLightValue(value)}
      onComplete={(value) => {
        returnLightValue(value);
        setBrightness(value);
      }}
      {...other props}
    />
  );
}
```

When I trigger `onChange` or `onComplete` from B, I can get the data to use in A and the `<Text />` can re-render:

```
import B from './B';

const A = () => {
  const [brightness, setBrightness] = useState(0); //

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Show the value is {brightness}</Text>
      <B
        lightValue={brightness}
        callBack={(value) => setBrightness(value)}
      />
      <Button 
        onPress={() => {
          if (someCondition) {
            setBrightness(50);
          } else {
            setBrightness(0);
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

But my problem is if I just click the `<Button />` in A, I can see the `console.log('lightValue is', lightValue);` change in B, but `<VerticalSlider />` doesn't re-render.

I try to send a Boolean props from A to B and set something like forceUpdate, but it will cause re render to much error.

I have no idea how to achieve it, any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue here is that you're using different state in both components.
So your actually referencing two different states.

I would lift all state to A and use B just a child component. Something like this.

B

```
const B = (props) => {
const { brightness, setBrightness } = props;
console.log('lightValue is', brightness);

 return (
    <VerticalSlider
      value={brightness}
      onChange={(value) => setBrightness(value)}
      onComplete={(value) => setBrightness(value)}
      {...other props}
    />
  );
}
```

A

```
import B from './B';

const A = () => {
  const [brightness, setBrightness] = useState(0); //

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Show the value is {brightness}</Text>
      <B
        brightness={brightness}
        setBrightness={setBrightness}
      />
      <Button 
        onPress={() => {
          if (someCondition) {
            setBrightness(50);
          } else {
            setBrightness(0);
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

What we have done here is declare a single state in the parent component. Whether the child or the parent alters this state, all relevant components are automatically updated.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: So I even don't need to use return call back, it's more easier to use. Thanks for your help.

Comment: here you are passing setBrightness as a function to the child component. So when the child calls the function with a value it sets the state.